# What is the purpose of response time distribution in locust.io?

Tags: python, locust

Would like to ask the experts here what is the purpose of response time distribution in [locust.io](http://locust.io/)? I could not figure out what does 50%, 60% means in the downloaded CSV.

Comment: I had exact same questions!!! thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It shows the percentage of request completed given time interval which in table below means that 50% of the total requests to home is completed 160ms and 66% of requests are completed in 290ms and respectively goes on.

You can make a risk analysis about the performance of the services with this table for example to cover 99% 2sec needed but for 100% 14sec 1% of requests has very long time waiting.

If your target is to have 300ms at most, you can just cover the 66% requests so you will take the risk of your 34% percent of user to lose.

```
Method  Name    #requests   50%  66%    75%  80%    90%     95%    98%   99%    100%
GET    /home    14151       160  290    400  600    800     1100   1700  2000   13934
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this and didn't find anything in the documentation. My best guess is that it is the percentage of time responses that are below the value given in the csv cells.

Comment: Just check what is distribution table in statistics.